# Wifi Connects in Kali not in Mint

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have a Dell Latitude D830 with a built in wifi adapter. I currently have a dual boot of Kali and Linux Mint. In Kali, I'm able to see and connect to wifi. In Mint I'm able to see and attempt to connect, however it always says the PW is wrong.

I know the PW isn't wrong.  I've reset the router countless times.  On the same machine I can connect if I boot on Kali.  Only difference I've been able to see is when I run `ip link show wlan0` on Mint I get:

```
$ ip link show wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:77:01:66:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and on Kali I get the same output except where it reads "state DOWN" it reads "state UP"

I've tried to manually `ifconfig wlan0 up` and it seems to work but still lists the state as down no matter what I do.

Any suggestions!?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` on Mint?

Comment: $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Well that is how it should be. What happens when you run `sudo ifdown wlan0` then `sudo ifup wlan0`? Specifically, what is the output of the second command?

Comment: [code]ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured[/code]

Comment: That is the first command, I would need to know the output of `sudo ifup wlan0` once you run it after you have run the first command.

Comment: sudo ifup wlan0
Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in Mint:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Edit it to appear as the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Once it looks like that, press `Ctrl-X`, then `y` when asked if you want to save, then `[enter]` when asked what you want to save the file as.

Finally, run `sudo reboot`, and see if your problem persists.